# New to C, need assistance with function related to structures

Tags: c

I need to make the second function (search_pb) print all matching names entered in the personal_info struct. Right now if there are two duplicate first names it only prints the first one. For example, if I added

First name: "Albert" 
Last name: "Einstein"
Phone number:35245

and also added

First name: "Albert" 
Last name: "Wesker"
Phone number:17367

it would only print the first Albert entered instead of both when I search for "Albert". Any ideas on how to change this?

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>
#include "libpb.h"

void add_person(struct phone_book * pb, struct personal_info person)
{
    int num = pb->num_people;
    strcpy(pb->person[num].first, person.first);
    strcpy(pb->person[num].last, person.last);
    strcpy(pb->person[num].phone, person.phone);
    num++;
    pb->num_people = num;
}

void search_pb(struct phone_book pb, char find_name[])
{
    int p;
    for (p = 0; p < pb.num_people; p++)
    {
        if (strcmp(find_name, pb.person[p].first) == 0)
        {
            printf("\nName: %s %s\n", pb.person[p].first, 
            pb.person[p].last);

            printf("Phone: %s\n", pb.person[p].phone);

            return;

        } 

    }

    printf("No entries with that name. \n");  
}
```

I was given the main function phone_book.c to work with so I just had to make the functions above and a header file:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>
#include "libpb.h"

int main () 

{

char cont;
char find_name[25];
struct phone_book pb;
pb.num_people = 0;
struct personal_info person;

printf("\n*********************************************\n");
printf("\n      Start with entering new contacts!      \n");
printf("\n*********************************************\n");
printf("\nWould you like to enter a new contact (Y/N): ");

while(pb.num_people < 20) 
{
    scanf("%c", &cont);

    if (cont == 'Y') 

    {
        printf("Enter a first name: ");
        scanf("%s", person.first);
        printf("Enter %s's last name: ", person.first);
        scanf("%s", person.last);
        printf("Enter %s's phone number: ", person.first);
        scanf("%s", person.phone);
        add_person(&pb, person);
    }

    else if (cont == 'N') break;
    else if (cont == '\n') continue;
    else printf("Error: User entered '%c'. Must enter either 'Y' or 'N'\n", 
    cont);

    printf("\nWould you like to enter a new name (Y/N): ");

}

//search phone book by first name and print persons

printf("\n*********************************************\n");
printf("\n        Now You can search for names!        \n");
printf("\n*********************************************\n");
printf("\nWould you like to search for a name (Y/N)? ");

while(1)
{
    scanf("%c", &cont);

    if (cont == 'Y')
    {
        printf("Enter a person's name to search for: ");
        scanf("%s", find_name);
        //scanf("%c", &tmp);
        search_pb(pb, find_name);
    }

    else if (cont == 'N') break;
    else if (cont == '\n') continue;
    else printf("Error: User entered '%c'. Must enter either 'Y' or 'N'\n", 
    cont);

    printf("\nWould you like to search for a name (Y/N)? ");

}
return 0;
}
```

I also already made the necessary header file libpb.h:

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include<string.h>
#define MAX 20
#define _CRT_SECURE_NO_DEPRECATE


struct personal_info 

{

char first[25];

char last[25];

char phone[15];

};

struct phone_book 

{

struct personal_info person[MAX];

int num_people;

};

void add_person(struct phone_book *pb, struct personal_info person);

void search_pb(struct phone_book pb, char find_name[]);
```

Comment: How about removing the `return` in `search_pb`? It stops the searching for other entries.

Comment: That does work however it causes issues with the other printf that prints "no entries with that name" when a name is not in the structure. It now prints "No entries with that name" after stating the second Albert's details.

Comment: Then do some thinking about how to prevent that/circumvent that issue. I hope you are capable of simple thinking.

Comment: I wouldn't have posted the question here if I knew how to circumvent the issue. I have little to no experience with programming. Simply telling me to "think" is not very helpful. How about a hint?

Comment: How about a variable that tells at the end of the loop if one or many matches were found? Issue the message of the variable is zero. I mean, that is not very hard thinking is it?

Answer (score 0):

A quick-and-dirty circumvention for this would be:

```
void search_pb(struct phone_book pb, char find_name[])
{
    int matches = 0;
    int p;
    for (p = 0; p < pb.num_people; p++)
    {
        if (strcmp(find_name, pb.person[p].first) == 0)
        {
            printf("\nName: %s %s\n", pb.person[p].first, 
            pb.person[p].last);

            printf("Phone: %s\n", pb.person[p].phone);

            matches++;
        } 
    }

    if(matches == 0)
    {
        printf("No entries with that name. \n");  
    }
}
```

You could however, e.g. change search_pb() type to int, and return the match count after looping through, so that you can print "no matches" in the caller instead of printing them inside the function.